# Firebase Cloud Messaging: "undefined" database getting created in IndexedDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am implementing web push notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). I have followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) for setup a javascript firebase cloud messaging and completed initial implementation for my app.
I am able to receive messages from firebase. But, I noticed that a database has created in IndexedDB and it named as **undefined**. This database contains a single store called **fcm_token_object_Store**, which all *auth, endpoint, fcmSenderId, fcmToken*, etc.

Please refer the following screenshot:

[image]

**Question:** Can this ***database_name*** is configurable? So that we can query in the application.